# Why did fighter jets shoot Steven's helicopter without caring if Steven would survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, 24

In the series *24*, season 3, last minutes of episode 22, catching Steven alive is very important for finding the rest of viruses so why  did fighter jets shoot the helicopter without caring if Steven would survive?

Answer (score 2):

Steven Sanders was close to board the helicopter and escape. Shooting it asap was the right decision, as SS is only slightly injured. Once in the air, the only remaining alternative is to shoot it killing everyone on board, including the terrorist.

I also believe that the 24 production was keen to show off with these 2 fighter jets conducting an approach and then shoot the helicopter.